# Unexpected outcome in granting read only privileges to new user

Tags: sql, mariadb, privileges

What I'm trying to do is create a new user named 'test' and only allow this user to read data i.e. execute only SELECT queries on the database. I executed the following SQL statements via the 'root' user to do so:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
CREATE USER 'test'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
CREATE USER 'test'@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'test'@'127.0.0.1';
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'test'@'::1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But when I access the database via the newly created user 'test', the user can perform more than just SELECT records. Can someone please tell and explain me what is wrong? I believe that this is the correct way to create a new user and grant privileges to it.

Thanks in advance.

PS Please note that I'm using MariaDB.

PPS The output of `SHOW GRANTS;` (evoked via user 'test')

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for test@localhost                                                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: please specify which database u are using

Comment: @Fahmina Its MariaDB.

Comment: can u please check grant option using this command "SHOW GRANTS" and let me know your results

Comment: @Fahmina Posted it in edit.

Comment: You can logout from db and again login through the user and try it to delete or alter some table. It should not be allow to do that. I've tried in my local db and it worked fine. Your syntax was correct

Comment: @Fahmina I did what you told but I still have the same problem. I can still instantiate a new table and drop with the user 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that you are performing your experiments on the database (schema) named `test`. This name is special in MariaDB/MySQL, and users have full access to it regardless the configured grants, which is why it is considered unsafe to have this schema in production environment.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show grants;
+-------------------------------------------+
| Grants for test@localhost                 |
+-------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost' |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use db;
Database changed

MariaDB [db]> create table t (i int);
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE command denied to user 'test'@'localhost' for table 't'

MariaDB [db]> use test;
Database changed

MariaDB [test]> create table t (i int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)
```